# Display content over image on hover/touch in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, imageview, hover, drawbitmap

I placed some circle images in my layout and I would like to display content when the user hover on them or touch an image. I tried to search on google, but I found nothing useful about this topic.

I would like to display (i.e. on `test1` image) a small window (*like a pop-up window*) with some text and one or two buttons when the user is hovering on the images.

Is it possible to do this in Android?

EDIT: This is the result I would like to achieve.
For example, in this case, when the user hover or touch the image, a popup appears and show addition options.

[image]

```
        // Draw circles
    canvas.drawCircle((canvas.getWidth()/2)-300, canvas.getHeight()/2,60,paint);
    canvas.drawCircle((canvas.getWidth()/2), (canvas.getHeight()/2)-300,60,paint);
    canvas.drawCircle((canvas.getWidth()/2)+300, (canvas.getHeight()/2),60,paint);

    // load bitmap..
    Bitmap test = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.img1);
    Bitmap test1 = MLRoundedImageView.getCroppedBitmap(test, 160);
    canvas.drawBitmap(test1, 468, 525, paint);
```

Comment: What does "hover" mean in a touchscreen environment? Are you referring to users with some sort of active stylus? Or, are you referring to when the user is using a mouse? For those, you can [try `setOnHoverListener()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnHoverListener(android.view.View.OnHoverListener)) to find out when the user is hovering over your whole view, but then you will need to determine if the user is hovering over a specific image.

Comment: I edited my first topic in order to clearify what I would like to acquire. I would like to display additional content both on hover and on touch. It depends on the devices..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the exact solution but i think popupmenu works for this

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, view_anchor);
popup.inflate(R.menu.your_menu);
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                                case R.id.button1:
                                    //code when button1 is clicked
                                    popup.dismiss();
                                    break;
                                case R.id.button2:
                                    //code when button2 is clicked
                                    popup.dismiss();
                                    break;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
popup.show();
```

put the above code inside your image onclicklistener

to put onclicklistener in your image put this

```
ImageView image1, image2;

in oncreate
image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.id_of_image1);
image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            //popup code
                        }
                    });
```

then in the xml put an id to your imageview

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/id_of_image1"
/>
```

Comment: Thank you, Gilbert, for your help. Since I'm pretty new to android, I will need to figure out how to add a "onclicklistener" on my bitmaps and then I will try your suggestion.. thank you!!

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help! I had to study few tutorials about menus and ImageView, but now I can finally run your code without errors.. thank you again!!! Now the manu is working fine!